# Fast and fluid horizontal scroll with scrollbar (CSS accelerated)

Tags: css, html, scrollbar

I'm trying to create an horizontal web page with a lot of images, and I've check some horizontal scrollbars.

All of them are based on a very long DIV and when you move the scrollbar below, it changes the "left" position of the long DIV.

But I've discovered ThisLife website, that has an extremely fast and fluid horizontal scrollbar that use transform3d to change the "position" of ALL elements in the div, and it's extremely fast, even with more than 100.000 images elements in the DIV.

How do they do it ?

I'd like to know how it's done, a very very very long DIV (500.000 px long!) with hundreds of thousands of elements, moving so fast and fluid. And all those elements are changing the "transform3d" position at real time while the scrollbar is moving

Here's a video to see how the elements CSS properties change and maybe to understand it. https://vimeo.com/100597987

So, what I'm looking for is a HTML/Javascript(jQuery) way to accomplish a horizontal scrollbar of a DIV with thousands of elements moving fluid, as the example, since other solutions (just moving the "left" position of a long DIV is very slow with thousands of DOM elements inside).

I think the transform3d is a solution, but I don't know how to accomplish.

Comment: transform3d is good because it is hardware accelerated

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I think translate 3d is a good solution. I made a simple slider built in AngularJS and css transform 3d before.  Here,

#### [Demo](http://jsbin.com/liqomeya/14/)

#### [Edit Demo](http://jsbin.com/liqomeya/14/edit)

You can strip it down, just get the core idea on how I created it and you'll be able to apply it on webpages.

Comment: It seems it's fine, but I don't know angular :-(  thanx anyway

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Maybe you can check out related questions or answers that can help you, or start with some fiddles and ask another question. Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

Try scrolling with native browser scrolling - as I know it's hardware accelerated. And if native browser scrolling is what you need, you can try [jQuery Scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar) that uses native scrolling via `scroll` event. But you will have to disable scrolling inertia as it does not generate `scroll` event.